# Running Apache Airflow locally - debug cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I'm running into this exception when testing a DAG on Airflow locally with aws-mwaa-local-runner:

Logs on Airflow for my task

```
[2023-05-18, 20:57:40 UTC] {{emr.py:571}} INFO - Creating job flow using aws_conn_id: aws_default, emr_conn_id: emr_default
[2023-05-18, 20:57:40 UTC] {{base.py:71}} INFO - Using connection ID 'emr_default' for task execution.
[2023-05-18, 20:57:40 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1851}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/emr.py", line 583, in execute
    response = self._emr_hook.create_job_flow(job_flow_overrides)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/emr.py", line 129, in create_job_flow
    config = emr_conn.extra_dejson.copy()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 400, in extra_dejson
    if self.extra:
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 573, in __get__
    retval = self.descriptor.__get__(instance, owner)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 290, in get_extra
    extra_val = fernet.decrypt(bytes(self._extra, 'utf-8')).decode()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 195, in decrypt
    raise InvalidToken
```

I updated my AWS token just before testing. Any idea on this error or how to debug it?

Comment: Fixed after running ./mwaa-local-env reset-db. You need to export your variables before running this command, it deletes them

Answer (score 0):

When I get this, I find using the ./mwaa-local-env reset-db which completely resets the metadatabase (so do not do this if you need that) fixes this issue for me.